MLE and limit distribution of ratio of parameters
I am solving an estimation problem and I can't make any progress. I have $ (X_{i1},X_{i2})^T $ iid from $\mathcal{N}_2 ( \mu , \Sigma)$. Define
$$
\lambda_j = \frac{\mu_j}{\sqrt{\sigma_{jj}^2}} , \quad j = 1,2
$$
How I can find the MLE of $\lambda = (\lambda_1, \lambda_2) $? and what can I apply to find the limit distribution of $\hat{\lambda}$? I had planned to find the Lambda's MLE using the usual procedure and find the estimators of the $\hat{\mu}_j$ and $\hat{\sigma}_j^2$. But to find the limit distribution I have no idea, I suppose multivariate CLT must be applied but I don't know much about it. I appreciate any suggestions or books from which I can get information.
